# DIY Oven heater

Tags: heat

I was not exactly the best studier in my class, when everything was explained, but I suddenly got interest in electrical engineering and now - how heaters are made.
I may not attempt to make one, before I educate myself a little. But it is just puzzling me and I cannot rest without knowing the answer - How are oven heaters made.

1. If you take a copper tube or kanthal/nichrome wire and give it a voltage so that they heat - isn't that short circuiting the voltage source?
2. How to determine what wattage is going to be needed to achieve the desired temperature? Let's say I want to achieve temperature levels up to 200o Celsium. This means the tube/wire itself must be somewhat hotter so that it provides this temperature in an area of say a pack of cigarettes.

I know that the diameter (thickness), the material, the length matter as well as the way they are formed - these factors are remotely related to the resulting resistance and wattage needed, but I am unaware of the right formulas to calculate them based on my expectations.

Comment: downvoter: What's wrong with my question? :)
I don't want my question to be bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The heating wire has a finite resistance and you can use ohm's law to determine how much current will flow through the wire given the voltage.  You can also calculate the power using voltage times current.  The power supply needs to be able to supply the current without damage, but as long as it can source the calculated current, you will not have a "short circuit" situation.  Be aware that depending on what the wire is made out of, the resistance may vary substantially with the temperature.

Calculating the resulting temperature involves doing an energy balance calculation and requires the thermal characteristics of the enclosure the heater is mounted in.  Generally, heaters are capable of generating much higher temperatures that are desired and a thermostat / temperature sensor is used to turn the heating element on and off to regulate the temperature.  Where accurate temperature controls are needed, a thermistor, thermocouple or other temperature sensor is used with a PID controller to regulate the temperature.

Comment: Can you explain why "as long as the power supply can source the calculated current, you will not have a "short circuit" situation."

Comment: Let's say you have a 6 ohm resistance in the wire and a 12V power supply.  Ohm's law says I = E / R, so I = 12 / 6 -> current = 2 amps.  As long as your 12V power supply is rated for at least 2A, you are fine.  Using a power supply rated for a higher current will not cause an issue, the wire will only draw 2A regardless as long as the voltage is 12V.  Note that this assumes that the resistance of the wire is constant which is not true.  For almost all materials, the resistance goes up at the temp rises so measure and rate at room temperature and add 50% to be safe.

Comment: I knew that. The the power supply is rated 80Amps (x4 Li-ions) but I thought the wire does not "draw" power, but only conduct it ..like a wire. And a wire connected to both terminals is short circuiting the battery. Given the continuing misunderstanding I suspect that I am not understanding something very basic from the concept and sound dumb.

Comment: All conductors have resistance and convert some of the power to heat.  Normally this is (hopefully) a small percentage of the power and the temperature rise is minimal.  Using Lithium-ion batteries as the power source introduces additional problems.  Your lithium ion batteries may not be rated for 80A continuous, like the wires they have internal resistance and heat up with current flow.  You also have to stop discharging the batteries at their minimum cell voltage or you will damage them.  Using lithium-ion batteries at very high currents requires careful design and can be dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

These are all the equivalents of Ohm's Law that relates resistance to current and power from a voltage source in this case.

[image]

I assume you can figure this out on your own.

The temperature rise due to Energy (heat) depends on the mass and power to heat up over time.  But for a steady state temperature rise, it can be done with Power [Watts] and Thermal resistance ['C/W] to determine the Temp rise of each layer and each layer have a certain thermal resistance, with metal having a low resistance and insulators like carbon having a higher resistance and  air having a higher resistance assuming convection flow.    But like Ohm's law with series Resistors, Temp rise = P * (R1 + R2 +R3 ...) where R applies to heat layer of thermal resistance with the hottest part at the heat source.

In electronics it is often done in layers with R jcn-case + R case-heatsink + R heatsink-ambient all added together to determine the internal junction temp rise above ambient ['C]

Comment: Electronics uses dozens of tiny equations. Consider Q = C * V; take the derivative, and dQ/dT = dC/dT*V + C*dV/dT; if C is constant, we just have dQ/dT = C * dV/dT, which we can rewrite as I = C * dV/dT; using that, we compute how large a filter capacitor (in the power supply) is needed in European systems assuming a fullwave rectifier (producing 100Hz ripple) is needed for 0.1 volt ripple and 10 amp surge currents in a 200 watt audio power amplifier: rearrange the equation, we have C = I * dT/dV = 10 amps * 0.01 seconds / 0.1 volts = 1 farad capacitor. Go explore power supply thinking.